# If you want to understand evolution from a genetics standpoint what are some must reads be it books or textbooks?

Tags: genetics, evolution, population-genetics, book-recommendation

The question basically sums it up. I'm looking for books/textbooks that explain evolution from a genetic perspective.

Comment: So your question is about your problem, not a problem in biology. I suggest re-reading the [Tour] for examples of the types of biological questions that are on-topic here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_synthesis_(20th_century)

Answer (score 0):

For a historical perspective and summary, see [here](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.94.15.7691).

For a textbook that works through the math from a very simple foundation, see [here](https://felsenst.github.io/pgbook/pgbook.html). (Felsenstein, J. *Theoretical Evolutionary Genetics*, 2019).